# Ruby on Rails - jQuery UI Touch Punch

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I'm trying to use jquery-ui sortable(), the function has has to work on both mobile devices and desktop computers.

sortable() works fine when I use the mouse button or the touch screen on my laptop but not in mobile devices.

The app is built using Ruby on rails. I added jQuery using a gem but 'jQuery UI' and 'jQuery UI Touch Punch' by copying the source files into app/assets/javascripts.

The application.js has following lines:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.ui.touch-punch.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_directory ./jquery_plugins
//= require bootstrap.min
```

In the source of the app, I can find the following lines:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It seems like it does not matter if I remove jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js (which I thought should solve this problem) from the source.

Any advice is appreciated :-)

Comment: Have you tried requiring touch punch last so anything that happens in `jquery_ujs` doesn't overwrite it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that seemed to make no difference :-/

Comment: What does your app-specific js file look like? For instance, if you are sorting projects, you should have a projects.js (or projects.js.coffee) file that looks like: 
jQuery ->
  $('#projects').sortable
    axis: 'y'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Touchpunch](https://github.com/geothird/touchpunch-rails) for the rails asset pipeline. Works perfect with android and ios devices.

Gemfile

```
gem 'touchpunch-rails'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery.ui.touch-punch
```